# SCSS variables alignment in PhpStorm

Tags: sass, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2016.1

How to easily format fragments of code like the one below in PhpStorm?

**before:**

```
$some-var-1: 0;
$some-longer-name: 1px solid true;
$some-variable: 3px;

.className {
  border:       $some-longer-name;
  padding   :    $some-variable; 
}
```

**after:**

```
$some-var-1      : 0;
$some-longer-name: 1px solid true;
$some-variable   : 3px;

.className {
  border: $some-longer-name;
  padding: $some-variable; 
}
```

As you can see variable assignments are formatted in one way and the rest of the code in another way.

By default I can set auto formatting so it formats like it's `.className` but how can I make PhpStorm so the variables format in the way shown in the second example? It would be best if I could format all cases in one file at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9211 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.